# SslStream on Mono not fully closing

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, xamarin, mono

I am currently working with a server application we have designed to communicate with a Xamarin mobile app. We are using an old messaging library that makes a connection with a `TcpClient` and keeps the connection open (with a heartbeat message every 3 seconds). We added SSL to the library by wrapping the `TcpClient` stream with an `SslStream`. We have run the server application on Windows and it works well, but our ultimate target is  `Mono` on a BeagleBoneBlack.

However, when we close the stream and the client on the mobile app side and then attempt to re-initiate a new connection, the `SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(...)` will not complete on the server. However, if I completely close the mobile app, the server will throw an exception. At that point, I re-open the app, and can reconnect without any issue.

So it seems something low level is not being closed on either the app or the server side. What is odd is that I run the exact same code on both when the server is running on windows and I don't have an issue.

Here is my code that closes/disposes the stream

```
public async Task Disconnect()
{
    if (!UseAsync)
    {
        semaphore.Wait();
    }
    try
    {
        if (UseSSL)
        {
            SslStream?.Close();
        }
        Client?.GetStream()?.Close();
        Client?.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Assuming we had an exception from trying to close the sslstream
    {
        logger.Error(ex, "Did not close/dispose correctly: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        SslStream = null;
        Client = null;
        if (!UseAsync)
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: It shouldn't be significant since the issue seems to lie at the server somewhere, and the client and server ssl code is almost identical, but in case someone asks, here is the client disconnect code

```
public async Task Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        if (UseSSL)
        {
            _sslStream?.Close();
        }
        Client?.GetStream()?.Close();
        Client?.Close();
    }
    catch // Assuming we had an exception from trying to close the sslstream
    {
        // Ignore exceptions since we've already closed them
    }
    finally
    {
        _sslStream = null;
        Client = null;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

It should also be noted that I've found at least one [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=976638) that looks like it's the same issue I'm dealing with. It doesn't appear from this bug report that it has ever been resolved, but I found other reports that seemed to reflect a similar issue in the mono framework and it was resolved. Additionally, I have added code to send some "dummy" data from the client after the connect ant it seems to have no affect.

**Edit 3:** I ultimately receive this exception on the client side

```
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00360] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:533
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I almost feel silly answering this, but I feel others could end up in my situation out of equal ignorance, so hopefully this helps someone out with a similar architecture.

What happened is that I created a self signed certificate and had it in my project folder, so the same certificate was being used on all of my "server" instances. What was happening is that, due to some internal caching of the SSL session cache, after connecting to one device, it would cache its information and then re-use that information when connecting the next time. The result would be that, since the self-signed certificate used the same host name for all devices, once it tried to reconnect to device B after being connected to device A, it would attempt to re-use device A's cached information (as far as I can tell) The reason this didn't initially make sense is that I could connect and disconnect to multiple different Windows servers over and over again, but only when connecting to Mono servers did I see this issue. As a result, it still seems to be a bug in either Windows or Mono's SSLStream implementation (since, in a perfect world, they are identical), but unfortunately I don't have the time to dig through the de-compiled source code to find it. And frankly, it probably doesn't matter because **what I was doing was breaking the whole notion of an SSL connection anyways.**

Ultimately, I created a function to programmatically generate a unique certificate for each device using Mono.Security and then provide a mechanism to provide the client with the unique hostname (even though the client is connecting directly to an IP address).